# Sort and merge arraylist

Tags: java, android, google-maps, arraylist

I have an ArrayList> called coordinates which has 3 lists: one with a variable called hr, one with the latitude and one with the longitude. In each of these there are thousands of entries. My idea was to map all this variables in a map (lol) where a dot of a color (depending on hr) was placed in the position specified by the latitude and logitude. This is how I am currently doing it. I have a standard activity with google maps. At the end of the onCreate I call:

```
paint()
```

What this function does:

```
/*Paint the dots of locations*/ 
private void paint (){
    //Paint the city with the blood of my enemies
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> coordinates = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> lat = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> lon = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> hr = new ArrayList<String>();
    coordinates = readfile(); #Import file from downloads and process it, takes 0.5sec for over 6000 entries.
    /*Here and down takes 1 minute for the same number of entries*/
    lat = coordinates.get(0);
    lon = coordinates.get(1);
    hr = coordinates.get(2);

    for (int i = 0; i < lat.size(); i++) {
        //paint
        // Add a circle for high heart rate
        if(Integer.parseInt(hr.get(i))>100){
            Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat.get(i)), Double.parseDouble(lon.get(i))))
                    .radius(10) //size of circle
                    .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                    .fillColor(Color.RED));
        }
        else{
            Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat.get(i)), Double.parseDouble(lon.get(i))))
                    .radius(10) //size of circle
                    .strokeColor(Color.GREEN)
                    .fillColor(Color.GREEN));
        }

    }
}
```

I added some logs to check the times, and the importing and processing of the file takes 0.5 seconds. The rest takes 1 minute.

What would be a way of optimizing this? The idea I had was if it was possible to take all the spots that are repeated (same latitude and longitude) and use either the most common hr value or the average(?). I don't know how much this would help though if the user is on the move.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These simple things come to mind.

1. Initialize your `ArrayLists` with initial capacity to reduce its resize (this is somewhat a heavy task) by doing something like below. I don't know the code for `readFile()` so do that yourself.

   `ArrayList<String> lat = new ArrayList<String>(6000);`
2. Do not put `lat.size()` in the `for` condition.

   `for (int i = 0; i < lat.size(); i++) {`
3. Why maintain 3 `List`? I don't know the specific requirements but if my assumption is correct, you could do something like `ArrayList<MyCustomObjectWhichHoldsTheThreeValuesInOneClass>`

Answer (score 1):

**Test data:**

> 1:1, 1:2, 3:4, 2:3, 5:5

Not very clear what to do without your domain.
The standard solution to this situation is the omnibus multiple markers in a large one.
Etc =>

> 1:1.5, 2.5:3.5, 5:5

Also, I do not see you limit the visibility zone. Do I have to show you everything? If you see only 0:0 to 2:2, you need to visible only:

> 1:1, 1:2